QGIS basemap display becomes very poor when CRS is changed
I've been experiencing this issue ever since I started using QGIS. I tried using three different versions of the software and am currently using version 3.34 Prizren.
The problem is that when I change the project CRS, the basemap (any basemap) becomes of very poor quality: labels are almost unreadable and lines do not have a crisp display as they do in ArcGIS Pro.
Here is a screenshot before the CRS change (the default CRS is used, which is EPSG 3857 WGS84 / Pseudo-Mercator), with the OpenStreetMap basemap:

And here is a screenshot after I change to any other CRS:

As you can see the quality of the display is reduced. It is even worse when I use other basemaps, such as ESRI topographic. Before changing CRS (which is already not crisp):

after changing CRS:

I'v tried the things listed below, and nothing worked:

Changing predefined scales like described here
Changing resampling method (in layer properties) to cubic
Zooming to native resolution (this one works sometimes a little)

Has someone experienced the same, and discovered a way to fix this?

That's to be expected, if you want base map tiles to look good you should make sure they are in the projection of your map

As said in just above, raster tiles displayed in another CRS than their native one need to be reprojected on the fly. They end-up streched/warped and nothing can really be prevented to avoid poor/loss of quality (one native pixel never matches on pixel on your screen). If you cannot use the raster basemap CRS as your project's projection, you might want to use a vector basemap which will not suffer the same kind of issue

Yes, try an OpenStreetMap vector tile server. Add using the "Vector Tiles" section in Browser or Data Source Manager.   The ArcGIS OSM vector tile service is ok https://basemaps.arcgis.com/arcgis/rest/services/OpenStreetMap_v2/VectorTileServer

It would help if you could substantiate your claim that the ArcPro versions are crisper by supplying screenshots of the identical areas.

Maybe this answer helps to increase the quality: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/385581/qgis-3-10-and-3-16-mac-bad-resolution-and-vanishing-wms-wmts-layers/388587#388587

I tried working with a vector basemap and it worked! I can't believe I finally solvend my problem. Il downloaded the MapTiler plugin and now everything is crisp. Thank you for answering.
